# How to enable a sticky file-Preview in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, preview

I'm currently working with multiple markdown files simultaneously and using the preview feature. However, every time I switch my focus to another markdown file, the preview also changes and displays the content of the newly focused file.

Is there a way to prevent this behavior and make the preview stay associated with the specific file I initially opened it for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `...` menu of the Markdown preview is the option: **Toggle Preview Locking**

Comment: is there also a way to set it as default?

Comment: @Jason you can check the settings for the Markdown extension, not in my version of VSC, if not found create an issue at the VSC repo